# Closure Compiler: Avoid "missing return statement" warning when a return is guaranteed

Tags: javascript, return, google-closure-compiler

This function will always return `"foobar"`:

```
/**
 * @return {string}
 */
function foobar() {

    var x = true;

    if (x) {
        return 'foobar';
    }

}
```

When compiled with this command:

```
java -jar compiler-20150609.jar --js test.js --warning_level VERBOSE
```

this warning is raised:

```
test.js:4: WARNING - Missing return statement. Function expected to return string.
function foobar() {
^
```

Similarly, this function will always return a string:

```
/**
 * @param  {boolean} bool
 * @return {string}
 */
function convertBoolToString(bool) {

    var boolstring = bool ? 'true' : 'false';

    switch (boolstring) {
        case 'true':
            return 'yes';
        case 'false':
            return 'no';
    }

}
```

Again, the compiler raises the warning about *"Missing return statement. Function expected to return string."*

I know the warnings can be suppressed by adding `@suppress {missingReturn}`, but I'd like to know if there's
a better solution. Is there a "hint" that can be provided for the compiler's flow analysis? Maybe something
similar to a [type cast](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Annotating-Types#type-casts)
(which is useful in cases where type-checking doesn't accurately infer the type of an expression) ?

---

### Update

I should have made it clearer that I'm looking for a solution
which **only** involves "hinting" the compiler. For example: using a suitable
[JSDoc tag](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler) or supplying a particular
[CLI flag](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/blob/v20150609/src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/CommandLineRunner.java#L135)
to the compiler to alter its flow analysis.

I'm **not** looking for a solution which involves modifying the JS source code
to ["keep the compiler happy"](https://www.google.com/search?q=keep+the+compiler+happy).

The disadvantage of @chsdk's solution is that the return variable must be
initialised with a dummy value of the correct type. If the return type is a
[class instance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript#The_object_(class_instance)),
then a dummy instance has to be created, and the constructor may require parameters which must also be given dummy values.
In my opinion, this is a [code smell](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/code-smell/info): the dummy value of the return variable
will never be used, and it's actually a workaround for an unrelated problem (a compiler warning).

I'm looking for a solution like this:

```
/**
 * @return {string}
 */
function foobar() {

    var x = true;

    /** @alwaysreturns */
    if (x) {
        return 'foobar';
    }

}
```

Does the compiler support a JSDoc tag such as `@alwaysreturns`, or other similar "hinting" mechanism
for flow analysis? Maybe a CLI flag?

Comment: Maybe it wants you to make sure you always return something. Your code will logically always return a string but if you disregard the logic, a switch could not have a matching case => no return and the if expression could be false, skipping the body ==> no return.

Comment: try annotating  the inline return like this `function /** number */ foo(x) { return x - 1; }` . here `number` is teh return type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closure Compiler does not have any "hint" mechanism to modify the Control Flow Analysis.  You are stuck with disabling the warning group altogether, @suppress annotations or modifying the code.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use a variable to store the return string, which is initialized with a default value, here's the code:

```
/**
 * @return {string}
 */
function foobar() {
   var myReturn = "default";
   var x = true;
    if (x) {
        myReturn = 'foobar';
    }
    return myReturn;
}
```

And for the second function just return the string you don't need the switch statement:

```
/**
 * @param  {boolean} bool
 * @return {string}
 */
function convertBoolToString(bool) {
    var boolstring = bool ? 'true' : 'false';
    return boolstring;
}
```

Or even better:

```
/**
 * @param  {boolean} bool
 * @return {string}
 */
function convertBoolToString(bool) {         
    return bool ? 'true' : 'false';
}
```

Directly return the result depending on the inputed `bool` parameter, without any variable declaration.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I should have made it clearer that I'm looking for a solution which only involves "hinting" the compiler. I'm not looking for a solution which involves modifying the JS source code to "keep the compiler happy". I'm sorry for the misunderstanding. I've now updated my question.

Comment: Also, I know the `convertBoolToString()` function can be refactored to remove the `switch` and `boolstring`, but that's not the point. The purpose of the function is to demonstrate a situation which causes the *"Missing return statement"* warning due to limitations of the compiler's flow analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Add @suppress {missingReturn}  to the functions JSDoc.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I said in my question: *"I know the warnings can be suppressed by adding `@suppress {missingReturn}`, but I'd like to know if there's a better solution. Is there a "hint" that can be provided for the compiler's flow analysis?"*

Comment: What "hint" did you have in mind that wasn't a @suppress and doesn't involve modifying the code?  "@suppress {missingReturn}" is the "hint".

Comment: The purpose of a "hint" is to give the compiler useful information which the developer knows but the compiler doesn't. For example, a C developer who knows that certain functions will be called frequently/rarely can use `hot`/`cold` to hint the compiler's optimiser (see: [Helping The Compiler Help You](http://benyossef.com/helping-the-compiler-help-you/)). `@suppress {missingReturn}` is not a hint, because it doesn't give the compiler useful information. It doesn't help the compiler understand that a value will always be returned. It just suppresses the compiler's warning.

Comment: Closure Compiler supports a [type cast](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Annotating-Types#type-casts) hint: *"In cases where type-checking doesn't accurately infer the type of an expression, it is possible to add a type cast comment"* ([ref](https://goo.gl/ZjBLTH)). This hint helps the compiler understand the type of an expression. I'm looking for a [control flow analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_flow_analysis) hint which helps the compiler understand that a particular block of code will always `return` (or that a particular condition will always be `true`).

Comment: Sorry, there are no such hints.  I can imagine it would be possible to the enumerate all the possible values for a switch as a "hint" but that doesn't seem generally useful.

Have you seen CFA "hints" in other languages or tools that you have found useful?

Comment: OK, many thanks. Please could you post that as a new answer ("No such hints exist for the Closure Compiler"), and I'll accept it (which will mark this question as "answered"). The nearest CFA hint I've seen is [`__builtin_expect()`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html#index-g_t_005f_005fbuiltin_005fexpect-4059) in GCC, which "provides the compiler with branch prediction information" (ie: a branch condition is likely/unlikely). I was looking for a similar hint which would say: "This branch condition is guaranteed", or "This control structure will always `return`".

Answer (score -1):

You have to provide return value. But here in your code return value is conditional, this is why your are getting this error.

```
function foobar() {
    var returnValue = "default"
    var x = true;

    if (x) {
        returnValue =  'foobar';
    }

    return returnValue;

}

function convertBoolToString(bool) {
    var returnValue = "default";
    var boolstring = bool ? 'true' : 'false';

    switch (boolstring) {
        case 'true':
            returnValue = 'yes';
        case 'false':
            returnValue = 'no';
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```